# Need to develop a Web page to run on my mobile

Tags: html, tomcat

I have created an HTML page on my PC and I need to run it in my mobile for testing. I have deployed it in TOMCAT and I run it using http://IP ADDRESS (192.something.something.something):port/index.html

I can't access it outside my home network. I want to know do I need to add something to make it run outside my home network on other mobile phones..? I am confused.. Everything is new for me. Will appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the config settings from your internet service provider to make sure that the Port is open and you are not blocking outside connections via the port or IP address.

Go to your browser and type in your IP address, this should take you to your router settings and check the settings there.

Good luck!

Comment: I am not getting the settings on typing of IP in my address bar.. Is there any other setting or way to do this..?

Comment: Connect your computer/laptop directly to your router with a cable, and enter the address http://192.168.0.1 or http://192.168.1.1  if this still doesn't work, let me know which Internet provider you are with and I will take a look for you.